# sql query to bring last record in a group

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to bring the last record in a group. 
This is the query I tried to work with but it's bringing the first record in the group.

```
 SELECT 
"hba"."ID",
"hba"."session_number", 
"hba"."u_c", 
"hba"."u-v", 
"hba"."date"
 FROM "hba"
GROUP BY "hba"."ID","hba"."session_number"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "What's" "with" "all" "the" "double" "quotes"? Also, would be useful to explain what you mean by "last"...

Comment: Some tools produce SQL that way.  Cognos does, for example.  Makes my head hurt to read it.

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because this query would fail in SQL Server (and in almost any database engine except MySQL)

Comment: what do you mean by last record? can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Furthermore, what do you mean by "Group"

Comment: You are misusing the MySQL-specific extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this for more information. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html  This extension is a huge pain for inexperienced developers.

Comment: If i understood your question correctly then i guess you are trying to group records based on id and session number and there are multiple records and query is fetching only one record i.e. first record of that group and you want last record of the group.
Since you are grouping by id, i think you are not using auto-increment feature for 'hba' table and it can have multiple same id.
e.g. you can have multiple records with id 1.
If my assumptions are correct, you need to add 'order by id desc'.

Comment: @TusharBhaware yes that is correct. So all I need to do is add a order by id desc?

Comment: @Dagz200, You need to add only order by attribute.

Comment: the hba.ID is the client ID not the record ID.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here. It looks like your `ID` field is autoincremented. It looks like you want your query to present just one row for each distinct value of `session_number`, and that row should be the most recently inserted one (the "last one" as you put it).

Let's start by retrieving the ID of the most recent row for each group.

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, session_number
  FROM hba
 GROUP BY session_number
```

Then, let's use that as a subquery and join it to the table.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.session_number, u_c, u_v, date
  FROM hba AS a
  JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, session_number
          FROM hba
         GROUP BY session_number
       ) AS b ON a.ID = b.ID 
 ORDER BY a.session_number
```

See how this goes? First you define what you mean by "last row" and build a subquery to implement that definition.  Then you use that subquery to fetch the data you need from your main table. Then you order the final result set in a usable fashion.

For some reason, you didn't disclose in your question that you're working in Crystal Reports. You may find it helpful to use a MySQL client to create a view with the information you need from your database, then use Crystal to render the result set from that view.

Comment: The MAX() attribute does not work as Crystal report is giving me an error of me trying to enter this query in a Command

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT "hba"."ID", "hba"."session_number", "hba"."u_c", "hba"."u-v", "hba"."date"
  FROM "hba" 
GROUP BY "hba"."ID","hba"."session_number" ORDER BY "hba"."ID" desc,"hba"."session_number" desc
```

is all you need to do.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work its still bring the first record and the the most recent record (last record)

Comment: @Dagz200, i have edited query. Please check now and let me know.

Comment: still getting the same result. Sorry

Comment: @Dagz200 I think i didn't understood your question properly then. Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/424cde/1. Is that you really want?